# Can't connect bluetooth -- invalid pin or passkey (Android 6.0)

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, bluetooth

When I go to connect an Android 6.0 phone to either of the instant pot or car, I receive an error message that the device can't connect, because it has an invalid pin or passkey.  How do I work around this fairly glaring bug?  Is there a file I can edit?

Back when my phone ran a slightly older version of Cyanogenmod, it worked on both of these devices.  So, it's not the phone itself.  Also, I have a second Android 6.0 phone that I've tried to connect to the instant pot, and it has the same issue.  Thus, I am fairly certain it is a bug with the operating system -- just need to find a work-around for the bug.

Comment: One thing I've seen work for some people is to go to Settings -> Developer Options -> Services -> Bluetooth services, and then stop all the services. Then reset the phone. This didn't work for me.

Comment: Another thing I've seen work for some people is resetting their network connections: Settings -> Backup and Reset -> Reset Network Connections. That also did not work for me.